# bootstrap tour tip is not working inside scrollable Div

Tags: bootstrap-tour

```
function createToolTips(ids,text,positions){
    var steps=[];
    for(var i =0; i<ids.length; i++){
        var obj = {element:"#"+ids[i],content:text[i],placement:positions[i]}
        steps.push(obj);
    }
    var tour = new Tour({
        steps: steps,
        autoscroll: true
    });
    tour.init();
    tour.restart();
    tour.start(true);
}
```

tour is not working inside scrollable content.
how to fix this issue,